# Can I transfer my SO account into a new email address but keeping all other community accounts?

Tags: support, accounts

I have some Stack Exchange communities with an email Id which includes SO and I want to not only delete my SO account but I also want to transfer this SO account to another email ID before deleting.

So can I transfer only the SO account to another mail keeping all other communities with that email?

Comment: It sounds like merging before deleting. I expect the [Merge account FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) could help.

Comment: @rene it seems like _splitting_ rather than merging? OP wants SO to be linked to one email and rest of their logins with another. Right now it is already a single account.

Comment: @SurajRao yes you are right. How do I do that?I tried creating a new login in `My logins` and removed the old one. But that changed it for all other communities too.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't have two separate accounts in one browser session. That is an unsupported scenario.

Comment: Side note: as @rene pointed out having two accounts is hard and it is pretty much guaranteed that both will leak back to be network wide including SO and other sites. Unless you want to sell/gift your account to someone else (which is obviously against ToC and hence clearly *not* what you trying to achieve) I would advice against doing it for yourself.

Comment: Background:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login